# How to read value from gradle.properties in java module?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I have a project in Android Studio with a couple of modules.

- The `app` module. With `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`.
- The `androidLibrary` module. With `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`.
- The `javaLibrary` module. With `apply plugin: 'java'`.

I want to declare some variables in the project `gradle.properties` file and be able to read them from the `javaLibrary` module.

I have declared the properties in the following ways according [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) documentation...

- `mysuperhost=superhost`
- `systemProp.mysuperhost=superhost`
- `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_mysuperhost=superhost`
- `org.gradle.project.mysuperhost=superhost`

... and tried to read them this way with no success:

- `System.getenv("mysuperhost");`
- `System.getProperty("mysuperhost");`

I know how to read properties from the `BuildConfig` class, but this is a generateed class in the app module (with `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`), so this does not work for this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement about being unable to use BuildConfig is not entirely accurate, as you can use Java reflection to find the public static members of BuildConfig as long as you know its fully qualified package.

Say the full package name of your generated BuildConfig is com.company.app.BuildConfig.  You can get its Class object with:

```
Class<?> klass = Class.forName("com.company.app.BuildConfig");
```

Then you can use that Class object to pick out the fields of it by name:

```
Field field = klass.getDeclaredField("BUILD_TYPE");
```

Then you can get its value:

```
String value = field.get(null);
```

Comment: When I said I am able to read a `BuildConfig` member I meant I am able to do so from the `app` module. What I want to do is to read a property declared in the `gradle.properties` file from the `java` module.

Comment: OK, so you want to read them during the gradle build, not when the app is running?

Comment: Yes, the property should be available at runtime.

Comment: You can still definitely use reflection.  A big reason to use reflection APIs is to pick out things from classes at runtime without having to compile against any of their symbols.  I updated the answer to be more specific about this.

Comment: I'll definitely give it a try. Just to make sure before proceeding, does the `java` module need to depend on the `app`module?

Comment: No, this is a complete division of the two.  The Java module is simply having to make assumptions about what the app module contains.

Answer (score 7):

If you have some value inside of the your **gradle.properties** file like
**mysuperhost=superhost**
then write the following lines in the your **build.gradle** file (to grab property from **gradle.properties** file and add it into **BuildConfig.java** class):

```html
// ...
// ...

android {
    // Just for example
    compileSdkVersion 23
    // Just for example
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    // ...
    // ...

    defaultConfig {
        // Just for example
        minSdkVersion 14
        // Just for example
        targetSdkVersion 23

        // This is the main idea
        buildConfigField('String', 'MY_SUPER_HOST', "\"${mysuperhost}\"")

        // ...
        // ...
    }

    // ...
    // ...
}

// ...
// ...
```

After that build your project and you are able to use your value via **BuildConfig.MY_SUPER_HOST**

Comment: Thanks, but this will make the `BuildConfig` member available from the `app` module, I want the gradle property to be available from the `java` module. I'm working on the @Doug's solution. Will post it here if it worked.